# Generate ReturnUrl with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I currently have the following architecture

- Marketing Site (Landing Page)
- WebAPI
- SPA
- IdentityServer

I have included my user registration page in the IdentityServer project and have a link to this page on my Marketing Site.

My question is...is there a way I can generate the returnurl to the Spa from within IdentityServer.  Are there any helpers for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing out of the box for this, but it would work just fine if instead of having a link to the registration page, the link would be the `connect/authorize` request to the login page (which in turn would have a link to user registration page).

This sort of user login/registration flow is implemented almost everywhere now, so likely can also be called somewhat best practice. It would implicitly take care of your problem because the redirect uri would be included in the regular oidc request.

Comment: Thank you, that had pointed me in the right direction and is a completely valid approach. 
I've just dont a bit more googling and it looks like there is a url helper for this https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/authorize.html which I guess means I could also generate the url on the server.

Comment: In the end I went with your approach, makes more sense

Comment: @JimCulverwell No problems, you're very much welcome

Comment: Hi.. @JimCulverwell were you able to create a redirecturl inside IDserver 4? If Yes can you share the code snippet? It would be really helpful